# The application crashes after pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with 1 new thread, which works all the time and emulates key presses.
It looks like this:

```
private void kamikadze()
{
    InputSimulator inp = new InputSimulator();
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        inp.Keyboard.KeyDown(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
        inp.Keyboard.KeyUp(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
    }
}
```

I start it like this (and of course I close it when I exit form):

```
th = new Thread(kamikadze);
th.Start();
```

And problem is that when I click Ctrl+Alt+Del the application freezes and crashes after a few seconds.
Application works perfectly when I dont start thread.

I will be glad if you can tell me what this might be related to. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with the debugger attached? I believe you get an exception because sending keys while the desktop is locked is illegal. But you should try to collect some information about the error.

Comment: thanks to your comment, I understood what was going on, thank you!

Comment: Then it would be good if you could write an answer to your own question, so that if somebody else has the same problem, they find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just put try except to this part of code. Now it works perfectly

```
private void kamikadze()
{
    InputSimulator inp = new InputSimulator();
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        try
        {
            inp.Keyboard.KeyDown(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
            inp.Keyboard.KeyUp(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
        }
        catch { }

    }
}
```

Comment: The use of the so called "catch all" clause is highly discouraged and bad style, because it hides all kinds of errors that could happen. Instead, try to catch only the exception type that actually happens. Bonus points for adding a comment on why it is safe to ignore that error (catch with an empty handler is usually also bad)